# style.css cannot be found while my references to my php files are still functioning

Tags: php, html, css, phpstorm, filepath

I expect that it is a really stupid question and it must be some kind of newbie mistake but I cannot figure out why my index.php cannot find my style.css. The page was working the whole time until I changed the map structure too something more OO. Now I have the problem that my images and css files cannot be found but my php files are still functioning. I have changed the style references so it fits the new structure. Only it does not work. I have uploaded some images below to illustrate my problems.

This image shows my file structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ljLW.png

This image shows a part of my code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ljLW.png#1

I would really appreciate it if somebody is able to take a look at it. I am just not able to figure out what is wrong.

Here is the code in text:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <?php
    require '../inc/SliderFunction.inc.php'
    ?>
</head>

<body onload="Slider();">

    <?php
        require '../inc/Topbar.inc.php';
    ?>

    <div class="body">
        <?php
            require '../inc/Navigation.inc.php';
        ?>

        <div class="content">
            <div class="featured">
                <img id="1" src="../img/slider/gummybears.jpg" border="0" alt="Gummybears"/>
                <img id="2" src="../img/slider/sweethearts.png" border="0" alt="Sweethearts"/>
                <img id="3" src="../img/slider/lollipops.jpg" border="0" alt="Lollipops">
            </div>
            <div class="producten">
                <div class="product"></div>
                <div class="product"></div>
                <div class="product"></div>
                <div class="product"></div>
                <div class="product"></div>
                <div class="product"></div>
                <div class="product"></div>
                <div class="product"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php
        require '../inc/Footer.inc.php';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please actually include the code here.  As text.

Comment: What are the console errors?

Comment: @dowomenfart If I press f12 in the browser and look at the status of style.css I get a typical 404 Not Found error. That error is not really helpfull.

Comment: Have a absolute path instead of a relative path? I.E localhost:9000/css/style.css

Comment: @dowomenfart  I have an relative path at the moment. If I change it to an absolute path: localhost:8081/css/style.css I get the error (failed) net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: @ryanyuyu I have added my code as text to my post.

Comment: 1) What file is this ? 2) Where it's located in your project (path relative to the project root please)? 3) What the URL for it? 4) Is it only css that does not work .. or images as well?

Comment: @LazyOne 1) the text/code your seeing is my index.php, the file that it should refer to is style.css and slider.css 2) index.php is in root -> core and style.css is in root -> css 3) Sorry but I did not understood your question number three, if you are referring too my URL's in the post, one image is code the other image is my file structure 4) The css and the images do not work, only the references to the php-files work.

Comment: 3) What is the FULL URL that you are using to see this file in your browser?

Comment: @LazyOne I created I virtual host, so I use snoepwinkel.dev:8081. I can also use http://localhost:8081/workspace/Snoepwinkel/core/Index.php, while I typed in the full localhost link I found out that the images are visible but not when I use my snoepwinkel.dev:8081. With the full localhost link the css is still not working.

Comment: In such case I cannot help here as I still do not understand what sort of URLs are failing and why. You should check your Apache's (I assume it is) error.log or access.log -- you should clearly see what failing URLs are. Because right now stuff like `../img/` or `../css/` should work just fine (earlier suggested `localhost:8081/css/style.css` is not full/correct URL -- it should include `http://` or at least `//` in front.

Comment: @LazyOne I have tried different ways to link the php-file to the css file on the localhost:8081/workspace/Snoepwinkel/core/Index.php link and   for some reason /css/style.css is not working but now I have changed it to ../css/style.css and it does work on the long link but not on my virtual host: snoepwinkel.dev:8081. The reference was working before I changed the file structure but now for some reason the css and image files can only be found by the localhost and not by snoepwinkel.dev

Comment: 1) Please provide web server logs. 2) It could also be your server  configuration (I do not know -- URL rewriting/redirect or some another module) -- but this definitely has nothing to do with PhpStorm (conclusion based on info you have provided so far).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks to you I have found out what was wrong. My virtual host directory was the directory of the index: "C:/xampp/htdocs/workspace/Snoepwinkel/core" while it should have been: "C:/xampp/htdocs/workspace/Snoepwinkel" with the DirectoryIndex set to "core/index.php" instead of "index.php". It was a really dumb mistake but I am kinda new to php and virtual hosts. If you put the answer down below I will accept your answer as the right one. Without your help I would not have been able to solve this problem, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

it's not stupid question.

you should referenc your css files like

> "/css/style.css"

Comment: I have already tried /, but unfortunately it does not work for me. I do not know why cause / should take me to my root if I am correct and my root should be Snoepwinkel and from there I should be easy able to reach my css folder and css files.

Answer (score 0):

If I am seeing your file structure correctly, you have your php files inside a folder and trying to pull css files outside of the folder?  Looks really unusual file structuring. It should be more like this.

Root Folder

- css folder
- img folder
- includes folder
- index.php (then call your css without /   example: css/style.css  same with your includes and images)

The homepage / index.php should be the first page on the main root and every folder goes inside from there.

Comment: I have made a map core for the webpages so they are not standing between img, inc and css but just in one place. Index is also in this map, the structure is root -> core

Comment: I see someone already asked you to try absolute path instead of a relative path. Is there anyway you can try it on a live sever with active domain. It looks like you are trying to run things local host. There might be some complications there.

Comment: I do not own a live server with an active domain. So I am not able to test it over there. You are right about that I am trying to run things local host ;)

Comment: Guessing that is the root of your problem. I have not worked locally in many years. Good luck.

Comment: still thanks for your help. My problem is solved, LazyOne helped me finding the mistake I have made.